# How can I write float data from a .txt file to a 2-dimensional array w/ VS2017?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, visual-studio-2017, file-read

How can I read float data from a *.txt* file:

```
8.9 789.3 845.6
2.45 2.25 2.05
```

. . .and write each float into an array element. I've looked online and I can't find a clear answer or tutorial on how to do this. I'm using **VS2017 Enterprise**, and I already have the *.txt* file in my Project's Resource file.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: use [strtof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) to convert the values in the lines that you read in.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example  you can use

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
FILE *f=fopen("file.txt","r");
float a;
char b[255];
while(!feof(f)){
        fscanf(f,"%s",b);
        a=atof(b);
printf("%f\n",a);

} fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: I would rather sugest reading strings and the scsaning. it avoids problems with new lines etc.

Comment: `while(!feof(f)){
        fscanf(f,"%s",b);` is weak 0.  Check the return value of `fscanf()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have always gained more from an explanation of *how* one reached an answer over just code so here is how I would think through this problem (assuming little knowledge of the chosen language):

First, I need to read through a file. I now go online and search for how to read a file. I find several examples of reading files and pick what makes most sense for me (whether that's streaming the file or reading the whole file into a `char *`). Once I have figured that out, I can move on to figuring out the 2d array.

To build the 2d array, I first need to initialise a 2d array to the correct size. *If one is a true beginner, that might mean looking up how to do initialise a 2d array.* Then I can move on to filling the array.

Now, I iterate over the 2d array. *If one is a true beginner, that might mean looking up how to iterate over a 2d array.* For every cell in the 2d array, I need to parse out the next float from the file and insert it into the cell.

This part, depending on how you've chosen to read the file, can be done in many ways. Assuming that you are streaming the file, you would need to read the next "word" and then transform that text into a float. To do that I would probably search things like 'read text until space or newline in C' and 'convert string to float in C'.

Then all that's left to do is to test it!
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use system.IO to read text in the file and then use C# split to convert to an array.

Namespaces

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
```

In your code

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
// Open the file to read from.
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
string[] strarray = readText.Split(Convert.ToChar(' '));
```

If you want to convert it to `double` array. Use `linq`

```
double[] darray = readText.Split(Convert.ToChar(' ')).Select(n => Convert.ToDouble(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: OP tagged C and C++, not C#

Answer (score 0):

> float data from a .txt file to a 2-dimensional array
>
> can't find a clear answer or tutorial on how to do this.

Pseudo code outline

Make these functions

```
// return 1: success
// return 0: failure
// return -1: EOF or end of line
int read_one_float(FILE *stream, float *f) 
  fgetc(): read leading white space, if \n encountered, return -1
  ungetc(): put non white space character back in stream
  if f == NULL, form a dummy location to save data
  scanf("%f", f) and return its value

// return > 0: return count of float
// return 0: failure
// return -1: EOF
int read_one_line(FILE *stream, float *f) 
  count = 0
  repeatedly 
    call read_one_float(f)
    if (response != 1) return count
    if (f not NULL) f++
    count++;
  return count

// return > 0: return count of lines
// return 0: failure
// return -1: EOF
int read_FILE(FILE *stream, float **f, int *width)  
  line = 0;
  *width = 0
  repeatedly 
    call read_one_line(f)
    if (response <= 0) return line
    *width = max (*width, response)
    if (f not NULL) f++
    line++;
  return line
```

Put together

```
int main()  
  open file
  width = 0
  line count = read_FILE(file, NULL, &width);
  allocate f float[count][width]
  REWIND file
  read_FILE(file, f, &width);
  close file

  do something with f

  deallocate
```